# what's wrong with the code using shared_ptr with pure virtual base class

Tags: inheritance, shared-ptr

This code does not compile, but i couldnot find what is wrong with the code. I think `shared_ptr` matters.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual const void test() const = 0;
  ~A() {  }
};
class AImpl : public A {
public:
  const void test() const {
    std::cout << "AImpl.test" << std::endl;
  }
};
class B {
public:
  B() {  }
  ~B() { 
  }

  shared_ptr<A> CreateA() {
    a_ = make_shared<AImpl>(new AImpl());
    return a_;
  }
private:
  shared_ptr<A> a_;
};

int main() {

  B *b = new B();
  shared_ptr<A> p = b->CreateA();
  if (b) {
    delete b;
    b = NULL;
  }
}
```

Comment: Listen to the compiler for holy verses of the developer, by the developer, for the developers. No seriously, what is the compiler output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) incorrectly. You dont need to use `new` in `make_shared`, it defeats the whole purpose of this function template.

> This function is typically used to replace the construction
>   std::shared_ptr(new T(args...)) of a shared pointer from the raw
>   pointer returned by a call to new. In contrast to that expression,
>   std::make_shared typically allocates memory for the T object and
>   for the std::shared_ptr's control block with a single memory
>   allocation (this is a non-binding requirement in the Standard), where
>   std::shared_ptr(new T(args...)) performs at least two memory
>   allocations.

```
a_ = make_shared<AImpl>(); // correct
//a_ = make_shared<AImpl>(new AImpl()); // not correct
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot.

Comment: @LiZhang you could accept this as an answer by clicking check mark next to the answer if it helped.